# Only the else condition works in my google apps script Twilio Fax sending web app

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, twilio

I'm having an issue with my If statement.

Basically I set up a fax app with Twilio and Google apps script.

I give the user a choice to upload a document or send out one that stored on my Google drive.
If I upload a file it works. But if I check the checkbox to send a pre-set document, which I'm trying to accomplish by using the If statement it doesn't send.

I troubleshooted, and found that the If statements is getting a TRUE and FALSE value.

I think the problem is that when there is no file passed into the function it doesn't work. The thing is I'm avoiding the file by the If statement so why is it not working.

Below is my HTML file and server side apps script.

Any suggestions?

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');

}

function uploadFiles(blob, name, number, test) {
 
       //get destination number
  var num = number;
  var prefix = "+1";
  var removeDashes = num.replace(/-/g,"");
  var fullNumber = prefix + removeDashes;
  
  var output;
if (test){
output = "APPLICATION SENT!";
}else{
output = "FAX SENT!";
}
  
    var url;
  if (test) {
  var appl = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxx');
  var appurl = appl.getDownloadUrl();
    url = appurl;  

  } else {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxx');
    var blob = blob.split(",");
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(blob[1]), 'application/pdf');
    var fileName = blob.setName(name).getName();
    var file = folder.createFile(blob); 
  
      //allow access to Twilio
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  
  //get file url
  var id = file.getId();
  var getfile = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var getnewurl = getfile.getDownloadUrl();
   var url = getnewurl;
 }
  
   //send fax
  var faxUrl = "https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes";
         
        var payload = {
          "From" : "+1888888888",
          "To": fullNumber,
          "MediaUrl" : url,
          "Method" : "POST",
        };
        
        var options = {
          "method" : "post",
          "payload" : payload
        };
        
        options.headers = {    
          "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        };
        UrlFetchApp.fetch(faxUrl, options);
  
  return "succes" + output;
}
```

Here is the HTML file: (I removed the `<style>` in order to shorten)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

function upload() {
var file = document.getElementsByName('myFile')[0].files[0];
var number = document.getElementsByName('Pnumber')[0].value;
var test = document.getElementsByName("entered")[0].checked;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
var content = reader.result;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(content, file.name, number, test);

return false;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}   

function fileUploaded(status) {
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<h1 align="center" style="color:darkblue">FAX APP</h1>

<h2 align="center">SEND OUTGOING FAX</h2>
<hr>
<form id="myForm" align="center">

<label for="pdf">Choose a PDF file to upload -- <b>OR</b>-- Check "SEND APPLICATION" </label>
<br>
<input id="pdf" type="file" name="myFile" >
<br><br>

<input type="checkbox" style="width:25px ; height:25px" name="entered">
<label for="entered" style="font-size:30px" >  SEND APPLICATION</label>

<br><br>
<label for="phonenumber">Enter Destination Number</label>
<br>
<input id="phonenumber" type="text" name="Pnumber" placeholder="Phone Number" >
<br>
<input type="submit" value="SEND FAX" onclick="upload()" >
</form>
<p><b>FAX DELIVERY STATUS:</b></p>
<div id="output"align="center"><b></b></div>
<br>
<a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?usp=sharing"
target="_blank">SENT FAX DOCUMENTS</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

BELOW IS THE NOW WORKING CODE OF GOOGLE SCRIPT SIDE AND HTML
THANKS TO @Tanaike's HELP

CURRENT GOOGLE SCRIPT SIDE CODE:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');

}

function uploadFiles(blob, name, number, test) {
 
       //get destination number
  var num = number;
  var prefix = "+1";
  var removeDashes = num.replace(/-/g,"");
  var fullNumber = prefix + removeDashes;
  
  var output;
if (test){
output = "APPLICATION SENT!";
}else{
output = "FAX SENT!";
}
  
  var url;
if (test) {
  var appl = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  var appurl = appl.getDownloadUrl();
    url = appurl;  
  } else {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

    var blob = blob.split(",");
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(blob[1]), 'application/pdf', name);
    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob); 
  
      //allow access to Twilio
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  
  //get file url
  var id = file.getId();
  var getfile = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var getnewurl = getfile.getDownloadUrl();
   url = getnewurl;
 }
  
    
   
   //send fax
  var faxUrl = "https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes";
         
        var payload = {
          "From" : "+188888888888",
          "To": fullNumber,
          "MediaUrl" : url,
          "Method" : "POST",
        };
        
        var options = {
          "method" : "post",
          "payload" : payload
        };
        
        options.headers = {    
          "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        };
        UrlFetchApp.fetch(faxUrl, options);
  
  return "Success - " + output;
}
```

CURRENT HTML SIDE CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

function upload() {
  var file = document.getElementsByName('myFile')[0].files[0];
  var number = document.getElementsByName('Pnumber')[0].value;
  var test = document.getElementsByName("entered")[0].checked;
  
        if(!test){
            var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            var content = reader.result;
        
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(content, file.name, number, null);
        
        return false;
        }
        
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
        
        }else{
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(null, null, number, test);
        
        return false;
        }
}
function fileUploaded(status) {
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status; 
}
</script>
</head>






<body>
<div align="center">
<h1 align="center" style="color:darkblue">FAX APP</h1>

<h2 align="center">SEND OUTGOING FAX</h2>
<hr>
<form id="myForm" align="center">

<label for="pdf">Choose a PDF file to upload -- <b>OR</b>-- Check "SEND APPLICATION" </label>
<br>
<input id="pdf" type="file" name="myFile" >
<br><br>

<input type="checkbox" style="width:25px ; height:25px" name="entered">
<label for="entered" style="font-size:30px" >  SEND APPLICATION</label>

<br><br>
<label for="phonenumber">Enter Destination Number</label>
<br>
<input id="phonenumber" type="text" name="Pnumber" placeholder="Phone Number" >
<br>
<input type="submit" value="SEND FAX" onclick="upload()" >
</form>
<p><b>FAX DELIVERY STATUS:</b></p>
<div id="output"align="center"><b></b></div>
<br>
<a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?usp=sharing"
target="_blank">SENT FAX DOCUMENTS</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I saw your updated script, I was surprised. Because you had changed the Google Apps Script. By this, an error occurs. So I added one more modification point. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thanks! now it's working, I actually would like to keep the file name because I keep all sent faxes in a folder in my drive. I added back in the parameter `file.name` and `null` for the else statement and on the script side I added `name,`. I updated the code in the question. Thanks @Tanaike for all your patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to remove the error when `SEND APPLICATION` is checked without selecting a file.

#### Modification points:

- When the file is not selected, an error occurs at `FileReader` because `file` is undefined. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.
- In this case, I would like to propose the function `upload()` at Javascript side as follows.

  - `if (file && !test) {}else{}` is used. By this,

    - When the file is selected AND `SEND APPLICATION` is not checked, the selected file is used.
    - When the file is not selected OR `SEND APPLICATION` is checked, the file of `var appl = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxx')` is used.
  - About this, please modify the if statement for your actual situation.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify `upload()` at Javascript side as follows.

```
function upload() {
  var file = document.getElementsByName('myFile')[0].files[0];
  var number = document.getElementsByName('Pnumber')[0].value;
  var test = document.getElementsByName("entered")[0].checked;
  
  // I modified below script.
  if (file && !test) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var content = reader.result;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(content, file.name, number, test);
      return false;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(null, null, number, test);
  }
}
```

- In this modification, Google Apps Script side is not modified.

### Added:

I think that your current issue is due to that you changed Google Apps Script from the script in the initial question. In the current script, `name` is removed at Google Apps Script and Javascript. By this, an error occurs at `createFile`. Please use `name` as follows.

#### From:

```
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(blob[1]), 'application/pdf');
```

#### To:

```
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(blob[1]), 'application/pdf', "sample");
```

- In this case, the filename is a temploral. So you can use various name like "sample", "temp" and so on.
- **And when you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- And in your current script, `if (!test) {` is used. In this case, when the button is cliced without selecting file and cheking the checkbox, an error occrurs. Please be careful this.

Comment: I pasted your code but now it doesnt work and the page redirects, see my edit to the question

Comment: @jack Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. At first, I noticed my copy and paste error. `uploadFilesss` in my answer is `uploadFiles`. I apologize for this. I updated it. And when I saw your added script, I think that `}` of `function upload() {` is not used. In this case, the script is incomplete. How about this?

Comment: that helped but the choose fiile option doesn't work only when you check the box it works. I updated my question to the current code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jack Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because in my environment, when the checkbox is checked, no error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide your current script for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I edited the question and included the most current script. I think the if statement is always reading the condition as FALSE so it's executing the else statement which is the checkbox option. Is there a better way to say in a boolean value if there is a file or not?

Comment: @jack Thank you for replying. The script in your updated question is the script for replicating your issue. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218333/discussion-between-jack-and-tanaike).